# Super anagram help for java

Tags: java

This anagram project works all good, but for some examples like "Narcissism / one man crisis" the output should be false because of the extra "s" in narcissism but it comes up as true. I am new to coding so I just need some help figuring this out.

heres the code that takes inputs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SuperAnTester{

public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String s1 = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter a second phrase:");
  String s2 = scan.nextLine();
  SuperAnagram tester = new SuperAnagram(s1,s2);
  System.out.println(tester.isSuperAnagram());

  }
}
```

here is the tester part:

```
public class SuperAnagram{

public String s1;
public String s2;
public char s1Array[];
public char s2Array[];

public SuperAnagram(String firstStr, String secondStr){
  s1=firstStr;
  s2=secondStr;
  }   
public void s1Char(){
  s1=s1.toLowerCase();
  s1Array=s1.toCharArray();

}

public void s2Char(){
  s2=s2.toLowerCase();
  s2Array=s2.toCharArray();
 }

public boolean isSuperAnagram(){
 s1Char();
 s2Char();

 boolean isSuperAnagram=false;

 if (s1Array.length > s2Array.length){
     isSuperAnagram=false;
     return isSuperAnagram;
     }

 else{

 for (int x=0; x<s1Array.length; x++){
     char let = s1Array[x];
     for (int j=0; j < s2Array.length; j++){
        if (s2Array[j] == let){
           isSuperAnagram = true;
           s2Array[j]= ' ';
        }

      }
    }
  }

 return isSuperAnagram;
 }
}
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the classes or methods you are allowed to use? There is a much simpler way to check for anagrams.

Comment: It is also more obviously not an anagram due to the "o"

Comment: So you set `isSuperAnagram` to `true` if `if (s2Array[j] == let)` is true ... and what happens if the next check are all false for every other char? Wouldn't it make to reset it (or directly return `false`) when you couldn't find a matching char for `let`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (s1Array.length > s2Array.length){
     isSuperAnagram=false;
     return isSuperAnagram;
 }
```

Didn't test your code, but it looks to me, that you should replace that **>** with **!=**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest to remove all spaces:

```
s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");
```

One of your problems is in:

```
for (int x=0; x<s1Array.length; x++){
     char let = s1Array[x];
     for (int j=0; j < s2Array.length; j++){
        if (s2Array[j] == let){
           isSuperAnagram = true;
           s2Array[j]= ' ';
        }
     }
}
```

As soon as one character matches you set isSuperAnagram to true forever.

Re-write to something like:

```
for (int x=0; x<s1Array.length; x++){
   isSuperAnagram = false;
   char let = s1Array[x];
   for (int j=0; j < s2Array.length; j++){
      if (s2Array[j] == let){
         isSuperAnagram = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (!isSuperAnagram) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh! You are right. Thanks for mentioning that. I will update my proposal.